# Binding to property of collection elements

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I use MVVM pattern in my WPF application. 
I have ObservableCollection Records in my ViewModel.

```
public enum RecordState
{
    NotChanged,
    Changed,
    Added,
    Deleted,
    AlreadyExist
}
public class Record
{
    public string FirstId { get; set; }
    public RecordState State { get; set; }
    public string CurrentId
    {
        get { return GetIdFromInstance(Instance); }
    }
    public MyStronglyTypedClass Instance { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Record> Records;
    // other code
}
```

In View i have DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding }" //>
```

What i have to write(if that possible) in ItemsSource="{Binding /* here */}", so that Datagrid Items changed to

```
Records[0].Instance
Records[1].Instance
Records[2].Instance
...
Records[Records.Count-1].Instance
```

Comment: Why not bind to the collection?  {Binding Records}

Comment: Because Datagrid is part of my UserControl, and i use that UserControl(and DataGrid) with MyStronglyTypedClass all around my code. And MyStronglyTypedClass have many properties and collection of **elements**. DataGrid's columns're created 1) dynamically (here the [idea](http://paulstovell.com/blog/dynamic-datagrid)) 2) Columns binding to **elements** in code 3) Cell Datatemplates are chosen dynamically depending on the Type of element

Answer (score 0):

`{Binding}` means that your ItemsSource is the DataContext of that DataGrid(probably inherited from ancestor elements).
What you should do is set the DataContext of your top-level element(Window, UserControl etc..) to your ViewModel class.
And then as Gary suggested:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Records}">
```

The link you gave about dynamic elements does the same in that matter, it adds more complicated element bindings and DataTemplates.